# How can I import text from item to DialogFragment TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

The `RecyclerView` has components with text, I need that by clicking on a component that has text for example "Chess", the `DialogFragment` opens and the text "Chess" from the `RecyclerView` component is transferred to the `TextView` which is inside this `DialogFragment`.

To get a key from my `item` layout file, I write this:

```
   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("item", String.valueOf(dialogSRS));
            dialogSRS.setArguments(bundle);
```

But what needs to be written in the `DialogFragment` so that our text is transferred there?

I am writing the following in my `DialogFragment` but it doesn't work

```
public class DialogSkatingRinkSchedule extends DialogFragment{
    TextView number_srs_2;
    TextView start_srs_2;
    TextView end_srs_2;
    TextView cost_srs_2_1;
    TextView cost_srs_2_2;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_skatingrinkschedule, container, false);

        number_srs_2 = view.findViewById(R.id.number_srs_2);
        start_srs_2 = view.findViewById(R.id.start_srs_2);
        end_srs_2 = view.findViewById(R.id.end_srs_2);
        cost_srs_2_1 = view.findViewById(R.id.cost_srs_2_1);
        cost_srs_2_2 = view.findViewById(R.id.cost_srs_2_2);
        
        Bundle getArguments = new Bundle();
        number_srs_2 = (TextView) getArguments.getSerializable("item");
        return view;
    }
}
```

My adapter

```
public class AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule.SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder> {
    public ArrayList<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule> mSkatingRinkScheduleList;
    public List<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule> mSearch;
    private AppCompatActivity mActivity;

    public AdapterSkatingRinkSchedule(ArrayList<ItemSkatingRinkSchedule> SkatingRinkScheduleList) {
        mSkatingRinkScheduleList = SkatingRinkScheduleList;
        mSearch = new ArrayList(mSkatingRinkScheduleList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_srs, parent, false);
        return new SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder(v);
    }

    public static class SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView number_srs, start_time_srs, end_time_srs, cost_1_srs, cost_2_srs;
        public TextView number_srs_2;
        public LinearLayout ll_main;

        public SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            number_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.number_srs);
            start_time_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.start_time_srs);
            end_time_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.end_time_srs);
            cost_1_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost_1_srs);
            cost_2_srs = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cost_2_srs);
            ll_main = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_main);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SkatingRinkScheduleViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ItemSkatingRinkSchedule currentItem = mSkatingRinkScheduleList.get(position);
        holder.number_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_number());
        holder.start_time_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_start());
        holder.end_time_srs.setText(currentItem.get_session_end());
        holder.cost_1_srs.setText(currentItem.get_weekdays());
        holder.cost_2_srs.setText(currentItem.get_weekends_and_holidays());

        holder.ll_main.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            DialogSkatingRinkSchedule dialogSRS = new DialogSkatingRinkSchedule();
            dialogSRS.show(((AppCompatActivity) v.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager(), "item");
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("item", String.valueOf(dialogSRS));
            dialogSRS.setArguments(bundle);
        });
        holder.getAdapterPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mSkatingRinkScheduleList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the arguments `Bundle` of a `Fragment` or `DialogFragment` by calling the method `getArguments()`. Since you put a `String` there previously by writing

> bundle.putString("item", String.valueOf(dialogSRS));

you should retrieve the value by using `getString("item")`. Then you can display the text from the Bundle with the `TextView` as follows:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_skatingrinkschedule, container, false);

    number_srs_2 = view.findViewById(R.id.number_srs_2);

    // assign other Views like before  
        
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    String myText = args.getString("item");
    number_srs_2.setText(myText);
        
    return view;
}
```